# Custom implementation of a Map collection in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an implementation of a Map collection that stores a pair of key and value items.
The error occurs during runtime when I try to register a key-value pair and hit this line.

`EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];`

I'm running out of ideas on what could be the issue, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
//Driver class to test output
public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMap<String, String> mapInstance = new MyMap<String, String>();
        myMap.register("Key1", "Value");
  
        System.out.println(myMap.get("Key1"));
        
    }
}


public class MyMap<K, V> implements MapInterface<K, V>{
   
    private EntryNode<K, V>[] mapEntryList;
    private int mapSize = 0;
    
    public MyMap(){
        
    }
    
    public MyMap(int capacity){
        this.mapEntryList = new EntryNode[mapSize];
    }
    
    //static
    public class EntryNode<K, V>{
        K keyElement;
        V valueElement;
        EntryNode<K, V> nextMapEntry;

        public EntryNode(K keyElement, V valueElement, EntryNode<K, V> nextMapEntry) {
            this.keyElement = keyElement;
            this.valueElement = valueElement;
            this.nextMapEntry = nextMapEntry;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return keyElement;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return valueElement;
        }

        public EntryNode<K, V> getNextMapEntry() {
            return nextMapEntry;
        }
        
        public final V setNewValue(V newValueElement) {
            V oldValueElement = valueElement;
            valueElement = newValueElement;
            return oldValueElement;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + keyElement + ", " + valueElement + "}";
        }
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return mapSize;
    }
    
    public V get(K keyElement) {
        EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];
        int count = mapSize;
        boolean entryPresent = false;
        
        EntryNode tempNode = firstEntry;
        while (!entryPresent && mapEntry != null) {
            if (keyElement == mapEntry.keyElement) {
                entryPresent = true;
                return mapEntry.valueElement;
            } 
            else {
                mapEntry = mapEntry.nextMapEntry;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void register(K newKeyElement, V newValueElement) { 
        EntryNode<K, V> newEntry = new EntryNode(newKeyElement, newValueElement, null);
        EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];
        boolean entryPresent = false;
        
        while (!entryPresent && mapEntry != null) {
            if (newKeyElement == mapEntry.keyElement) {
                entryPresent = true;
                break;
            } 
            else {
                if(mapEntry.nextMapEntry == null){
                    break;
                }
                mapEntry = mapEntry.nextMapEntry;
            }
        }

        if(!entryPresent){
            mapEntry.nextMapEntry = newEntry;
            mapSize++;
        }
    }
    
    public void remove(K removeKeyElement) {
        EntryNode previousEntry = null;
        EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];
        while (mapEntry != null) {
            if (removeKeyElement == mapEntry.keyElement) {
                mapEntry.keyElement = null;
                mapEntry.valueElement = null;
                previousEntry.nextMapEntry = mapEntry.nextMapEntry;
                break;
            } 
            else {
                previousEntry = mapEntry;
                mapEntry = mapEntry.nextMapEntry;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private int getEntriesSize() {
        return mapEntryList.length;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringOutput = new StringBuilder();
        for (EntryNode entry : mapEntryList) {
            stringOutput.append("[");
            while (entry != null) {
                stringOutput.append(entry);
                if (entry.nextMapEntry != null) {
                    stringOutput.append(", ");
                }
                entry = entry.nextMapEntry;
            }
            stringOutput.append("]");
        }
        return "{" + stringOutput.toString() + "}";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Java!=Javascript!

Comment: I removed the 'javascript' tag.

Comment: Can you show the error, please?

Comment: What kind of error occurs? Compiler error? If so: please include the error message? Runtime exception/error? If so: please include the stack trace. In both cases: please highlight the line of code causing the error/exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException `EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];`

Comment: This code does not compile. Have you shared all the relevant code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This code is wrong. There is no such interface called MapInterface<K, V>. The interface you looking for is : [Map<K, V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: And the inner class you defined EntryNode needs to be of the type: [Map.Entry[K.V]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). And you can declare it static by saying: ```public static class EntryNode<K, V> ```. That comment of //static relally does not do anything here, unless its a TODO comment for you

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I make a new map, and then call .get() on it.

```
MyMap<Integer, String> m = new MyMap<>();
m.get(5);
```

This constructor (the no-args one) means that `mapEntryList` is never set, which means it defaults to null. Thus, when the `get` is invoked, the first thing your `get` method does is *dereference* the `mapEntryList` field (the `foo[idx]` construct dereferences `foo`). Dereferencing a null value means: `NullPointerException` is thrown. Clearly the intent of your code is to return null if the key is not in the map, so, that part is broken.

Alternatively, I'll go with:

```
MyMap<Integer, String> m = new MyMap<>(10);
m.get(5);
```

This time, I call the second constructor. This constructor takes the 'capacity' value, tosses it in the trash, and makes a 0-sized array. Then, get is invoked, and your code runs:

`mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize];`

This cannot work; you cannot get anything out of a 0-length array. In fact, if you write:

```
int[] a = new int[5];
a[5];
```

(as in, you make a new array of size X and then ask for the element with index X), you **always** get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`: in java all arrays are 0-indexed. `a[0]` is the first element, and `new int[1]` makes a 1-size int array, so doing `a[1]` (asking for the second element) on a 1-size array is not possible (it only has one element).

There are about 50 other issues with this code, you really need to take it one small step at a time and debug this code: Instead of just looking at all this code and going: Uh, it doesn't work - you need to debug it:

Write some code, then run it. As you run it, 'mentally run it': Take pen and paper if you have to, walk through the code line by line and figure out what each line should be doing, by hand. Then check what you think should happen vs. what actually happens, either by using a debugger or adding a ton of System.out statements if you have to. There where the code does something different from what you thought? You found a bug. Probably the first in quite a large list of them. Fix it, and keep going until the bugs are gone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Does that mean the issue occurs when the get function is called rather than the register function itself? As in the values inside all the map are all null?

Comment: Straight from your register method: EntryNode<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntryList[mapSize]; - same code, so it'll always fail on you for the exact same reasons. The error occurs exactly where the stack trace says it occurs.